# Fail importing theano

Tags: python-2.7, theano

I could import theano ok yesterday. Today, when I want to import theano, it says "No module named theano".

But question is numpy and scipy could be imported and they are in the same address as theano. I first think theano might error in itself, but after I uninstall and install it again. It still just can't work.

I just upgrade my Mac to "El Capitan preview" today. Is there any relation between them.

Comment: Try to reinstall python and Theano from scratch. The upgrade messed your python/theano installation.

Answer (score 0):

In a python shell, type:

```
>>> pip install theano
```

If you don't have pip, download [getpip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and execute it (outside of the python shell).

```
python getpip.py
```

Then,

```
python
>>> pip install theano
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using something like [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) or non-stock python?

You might want to check the `~/.bash_profile` and add:

```
export PATH = /path/to/anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

If you have multiple installations of python, maybe you're executing the one that doesn't have theano installed.